# Object not rendering as expected

Tags: javascript, object

I need an object to render in tree like structure. For example, if an object contains an object, it has to be child of the parent object. Here is the codepen link: [Render object recursively](https://codepen.io/abalachandar/pen/pZrVGw?editors=1010).

```
var object = {
  'key1': 'value1',
  'key2': 'value2',
  'key3': {
    'childKey1': 'childValue1',
    'childKey2': 'childValue2',
    'childKey3': {
      'subChildKey1': 'subChildValue1',
      'subChildKey2': 'subChildValue2',
      'subChildKey3': 'subChildValue3',
    }
  }
};

function parseObject(obj, element='') {
  var keyValue = Object.entries(obj);
  var div = document.getElementById('container');  
  var ul = document.createElement('ul');
  var li;

  keyValue.forEach(function(key) {
    li = document.createElement('li');
    li.innerText = key[0];
    ul.appendChild(li);
    if (element) {
      element.appendChild(ul);
    }
    if (typeof(key[1]) === 'object') {
      parseObject(key[1], li);
      return;
    }
    div.appendChild(ul);
  });
}

parseObject(object);
```

TIA.

Comment: Please read this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can recursive construct the entire string and use innerHTML to add it to a div. this may be more efficient

```
var object = {
  'key1': 'value1',
  'key2': 'value2',
  'key3': {
    'childKey1': 'childValue1',
    'childKey2': 'childValue2',
    'childKey3': {
      'subChildKey1': 'subChildValue1',
      'subChildKey2': 'subChildValue2',
      'subChildKey3': 'subChildValue3',
    }
  }
};


function createTree(obj) {
  return "<ul>" + 
    Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj).map(function(key) {
      var val = obj[key];
      if (typeof val === "string") {
        return "<li>" + key + "</li>";
      }
      return "<li>" + key + createTree(val) + "</li>";
    }).join("");
    + "<ul>";
}

document.getElementById('container').innerHTML = createTree(object);
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this parser in my projects. It expects an object (or an array) as argument, and returns an ordered list (with sublists). You just have to append the result into the container.

```
function parseObject(obj){
  try{
    const element = document.createElement("OL");
    const keys = Object.keys(obj);

    if(keys.length  == 0){
      return document.createTextNode("(Empty object/array)");
    }

    for(let kindex in keys){
      const key = keys[kindex]
      const elem = obj[key];
      const line = document.createElement("LI");
      if(elem == null){
        line.appendChild(createTextNode("null"));
      }else if(elem == undefined){
        line.appendChild(createTextNode("undefined"));
      }else if(typeof elem == "object"){
        line.appendChild(document.createTextNode(key + ": "));
        line.appendChild(parseObject(elem));
      }else{
        line.innerHTML = key + ": " + elem;
      }
      element.appendChild(line);
    }

    return element;
  }catch(err){
    alert(arguments.callee.name + " - " + err.name + ": " + err.message, "error");
  }
}
```